# Creating featureCollection histogram with title

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to create histograms from a feature collection based on a property in google earth engine such that I can provide a title and axis titles. the `ui.Chart.feature.histogram` does not seem to allow for this. It does, however, provide the data for the chart correctly.

I have also tried using the `aggregeate_histogram(property)` method, converting that to a dictionary, and accessing the `.values()` and `.keys()` from the dictionary, and sorting them. This, however, puts the data in order but not logically, e.g., 3 appears right after 29, not before 4. Make sense?

What I'm getting using `ui.Chart.array.values()` and the dictionary values and keys, vs. the `ui.Chart.feature.histogram`:

[result of `ui.Chart.array.values()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvuAJ.png)

vs.

[result of `ui.Chart.feature.histogram()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G3WE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize the `.setOptions()` method could also be used on the `ui.Chart.feature.histogram`!! This allows me to provide a title.